# Why is this php script running so slow (Simple select)

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

This script is running really slowly when I try it in google chrome with the script URL , and I would like to know why:

```
<?php

    include 'config.php';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $playerEmail = $_REQUEST["playerEmail"];

    $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM players
        WHERE EMAIL = '$playerEmail'";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array('EMAIL'=>$row[0],
              'DATEOFSIGNUP'=>$row[2],
              'USERNAME'=>$row[3],
              'GENDER'=>$row[4],
              'JOB'=>$row[5],
              'LVL'=>$row[6],
              'HP_NOW'=>$row[7],
              'HP_MAX'=>$row[8],
              'MANA_NOW'=>$row[9],
              'MANA_MAX'=>$row[10],
              'STR'=>$row[11],
              'SPD'=>$row[12],
              'INTEL'=>$row[13],
              'XP_NOW'=>$row[14],
              'XP_NEEDED'=>$row[15],
              'GOLDS'=>$row[16],
              'NUMBERSOFITEMS'=>$row[17],
              'LOCATION_X'=>$row[18],
              'LOCATION_Y'=>$row[19]
              ));
    }

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

All my others scripts were made using $_REQUEST, so I dont believe it's the cause. Anything you can think off, feel free to share here.

Thanks alot folks !

Comment: Which section is running slow? Have you done any benchmarking?

Comment: Approximately how many rows does your query return?

Comment: This seems overly complicated; why not just return an associative array from the database? If you used PDO, you could even use `fetchAll` to dispense with the loop altogether.

Comment: See [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: By using `select *` you are potentially pulling more data than necessary; just because you don't actually use it doesn't mean it won't be sent. Now imagine how much slower this might be if someone later adds player photos (as BLOBs) directly to the table.

Comment: Not sure why I got so many negative reviews... Anyway, I will check theses solutions and come back on this thread, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to create an index on your EMAIL column is correct, but for future reference here's a quicker, safer way to code this with PDO:

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",
        $username, $password, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log("PDO connection failed in " . __FILE__ . 
        ", Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    die("Database error, please contact administrator");
}

$playerEmail = $_REQUEST["playerEmail"];

$sql = "SELECT EMAIL, DATEOFSIGNUP, USERNAME, GENDER,
          JOB, LVL, HP_NOW, HP_MAX, MANA_NOW, MANA_MAX,
          STR, SPD, INTEL, XP_NOW, XP_NEEDED, GOLDS,
          NUMBERSOFITEMS, LOCATION_X, LOCATION_Y
    FROM players
    WHERE EMAIL = ?";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$playerEmail]);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have an index om you `EMAIL` column to keep the speed up.

```
$sql = "SELECT *
    FROM players
    WHERE EMAIL = '$playerEmail'";
```

Create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nn_1 ON players(EMAIL);
```

Since your code is open to anybody using SQL injection go and read up on SQL injection and PHP PDO. Your code is even for SQL injection one of the easiest to hack (so really make this code better or you are in trouble).

Comment: *I can do this for you* That's nice to warn users about security risks but suggesting to use them is not constructive.

Comment: @A.L Using some humour to get a point across....

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, +1 for the index recommendation. I also support warning people about security risks, and I support using humor, but *irony* is often hard for readers to recognize in a text-only medium.

Comment: @BillKarwin Removed the irony :)